# Keeping a function from being defined twice

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to define a function in a template, but sometimes the template is called twice. I tried

```
<cfscript>
if (not isdefined("tested"))    {

    string function tested(required string component) output="false"    {

        if (arguments.component CONTAINS "internal") return 'N/A';
    ....


 </cfscript>
```

But I still get a

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe you can do what you are trying to do.

When you define a function in the code, even if you surround it by IF / ELSE, the runtime compiler is *still* going to parse the code for the purpose of creating the Java byte code needed to run it. So your class/function *is defined* twice with regard to code organization. The whole idea behind a function or component is that you move it *outside* of your procedural or logic code into it's own library or group of functions - that way it's easy to reuse. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news :)

Comment: Good point for suggesting organising the code better so that this sort of thing doesn't come up. It's symptomatic of poor design to have stand-alone UDFs floating around the place, as well as it is to have insufficient control of the code that results in this situation in the first place.

Comment: Adam, you are correct of course - but you need a smilin face so James knows you are not upset with him about it :)

Comment: StackOverflow told me off for using "+ 1" in my comment, so surprised they'd let me do something so flippant as adding an emoticon. James knows what I'm like already anyhow. ;-)

Comment: Really? I've never used plus one but I'm always using smileys. I like people to think of me as smiling and forgiving them of almost any coding foible - there but for the grace of you know who go I. Actually I think I just came from there.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to do it this way:

```
<cfscript>
if (!isdefined("tested")) {
    include "tested.cfm";
}
</cfscript>
```

And then move your `tested()` into `tested.cfm`.

Or if you're using CF11, you may try `include "tested.cfm" runonce=true;`

See: [Can you isolate code from being seen from CF10 compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704603/can-you-isolate-code-from-being-seen-from-cf10-compiler)